Grant execute only in localhost
I have a user that can be accessed from any host (we are currently in development). But I want to limit the execution of stored procedures only for localhost. The problem is that the localhost user is not recognized.
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'admin'@'%';
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH 'caching_sha2_password' BY 'my_password';

###########################
### STORED PROCEDURES   ###
###########################
GRANT EXECUTE ON MY_DATABASE.* TO 'admin'@'127.0.0.1';

###########################
### SELECT              ###
###########################
GRANT SELECT ON MY_DATABASE.MY_TABLE TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT SELECT ON MY_DATABASE.MY_TABLE2 TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
.
.
.

Executing this code throws me the next error.
[2024-11-23 20:59:09] [42000][1410] You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

Changing the host "solves" the error, but I want to limit the execution to localhost. I don't know if I just have to add a new user like this.
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'admin'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED WITH 'caching_sha2_password' BY 'my_password';

###########################
### STORED PROCEDURES   ###
###########################
GRANT EXECUTE ON MY_DATABASE.* TO 'admin'@'127.0.0.1';

###########################
### SELECT              ###
###########################
GRANT SELECT ON MY_DATABASE.MY_TABLE1 TO 'admin'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT SELECT ON MY_DATABASE.MY_TABLE2 TO 'admin'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
.
.
.

Or if there's another way without repeating the user definition

mysql differentiates between % and 127.0.0.1 so you need to specify if you want such grant for a single ip

A user to MySQL is the combination of a username and a fixed string which is the hostname. The hostname string can contain wildcards % or _, but it's still a fixed string.
If you query select user, host from mysql.user you will see that fixed string. That's the user entry.
You can GRANT privileges to the user only by the name it is defined. If you defined only one user named admin@%, then that's the only user that exists. You can't grant a privilege to admin@127.0.0.1 because that user does not exist.
You can define two users, one named admin@% and one named admin@127.0.0.1. These are two separate users, and may be granted different privileges.
When a client connects over TCP, it authenticates against the user whose host portion more specifically matches the client's IP address. In this case, if you connect from 127.0.0.1 (localhost via TCP), it will prefer to authenticate against admin@127.0.0.1 and once authenticated, the session will have the privileges you granted to that user.

i wonder how many times you answered this already

@nbk I search for duplicates every time, and I do vote to close duplicates more often than I answer a question. In this case, I couldn't find an exact duplicate quickly. I also read several MySQL manual sections but I couldn't find a concise explanation. I assume you've seen past answers of mine where I link to the manual and include excerpts.
